# ¿Por qué escanea el valor 9 veces, cuando el loop se ejecuta 8 veces?

Tags: c, bucles

En un ejercicio tenemos como tarea resolver lo siguiente:

Debemos de analizar el peso total de 2 equipos con el mismo número de miembros. Este número nos es dado al inicio del problema, para a continuación recibir los pesos de los jugadores alternando entre equipos (equipo1_jugador1, equipo2_jugador1, equipo1_jugador2,equipo2_jugador2, ...)

Mi problema viene cuando quiero analizar los pesos con un for, el programa lee los pesos 1 vez más que el numero de veces que se repite el loop. ¿Alguien que me pueda decir porque.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int team1=0, team2=0, weight=0,members=0;
    scanf("%d",&m);
    for(int i=0;i<(members*2);i++){
        if (i&1){
            scanf("%d ",&weight);
            team2=team2+weight;
        }else{
            scanf("%d ",&weight);
            team1=team1+weight;
        }
    }

if(team1>team2){
  printf("Team 1 has an advantage \n ");
    }else{       
        printf("Team 2 has an advantage \n ");
    }

 printf("Total weight for team 1: %d \n", team1);
 printf("Total weight for team 2: %d", team2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: El primer scanf lo tienes mal, haces referencia a la variable m en lugar de members. Revisalo. Por otra parte que intentas hacer en el if con i&1? Eso va a ser cierto en casi todos los casos (a excepción de 0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código está, directamente, mal y no compila.

En el primer `scanf`...

```
int main(void){
  int team1=0, team2=0, weight=0,members=0;
  scanf("%d",&m);
  //          ^
```

¿qué es `m`? ¿Dónde está declarada esa variable?

Vale, podemos asumir que no debería poner `m` sino `members`. Pero en ese caso ... ¿Por qué copias un código que ni tan siquiera compila? Es una falta de respeto hacia quienes te pretenden ayudar.

> Mi problema viene cuando quiero analizar los pesos con un for, el programa lee los pesos 1 vez más que el numero de veces que se repite el loop

Veamos el bucle

```
for(int i=0;i<(members*2);i++){
    if (i&1){
        scanf("%d ",&weight);
        team2=team2+weight;
    }else{
        scanf("%d ",&weight);
        team1=team1+weight;
    }
}
```

Si `members` vale, por ejemplo, 10, `i` iterará de 0 a 19, es decir, 20 veces exactamente... ahora bien, eso no quiere decir que el bucle no pueda dejarse más claro:

```
for(int i=0;i<members;i++)
{
    scanf("%d ",&weight);
    team1=team1+weight;

    scanf("%d ",&weight);
    team2=team2+weight;
}
```

Dado que el número de miembros de cada equipo es exactamente el mismo, nada te impide hacer las lecturas de cada equipo de forma secuencial.

Incluso podría mejorarse un poco más. Si te fijas, la variable `weight` es compartida por ambas lecturas ... podría ser preferible usar una variable para cada equipo ... y también podríamos limitar la vida de esas variables lo máximo posible, ya que fuera del bucle no tienen ningún sentido:

```
for(int i=0;i<members;i++)
{
    int weight1, weight2;
    scanf("%d %d", weight1, weight2);

    team1 += weight1;
    team2 += weight2;
}
```

Y esta lectura funciona porque `scanf` interpretará que ambas variables pueden estar separadas por un número indeterminado de separadores ( espacios en blanco, saltos de línea y tabuladores), por lo que descartará todos los separadores que se encuentra hasta dar con el siguiente dígito numérico.

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar, al final llegue a una solución parecida a la tuya, pero lo que no termino de entender es por que el loop que coloqué primero hacia que se leyerran datos una vez más que los que se esperarian en el bucle.

Comment: Tienes razon la 'm' es la misma variable que members, y el 'i&1' lo que hace es revisar bit a bit y me dice si es par o impar

Comment: @RalEs el código que has puesto está en un estado intermedio... de ahí que no compile. Es probable que en el bucle original tuvieses un `i<=` y de ahí que apareciese una iteración más

Answer (score -1):

Estimado amigo.

Imagina que pones como numero de jugadores el valor de 3, si calculamos las iteraciones que hara el bucle FOR serian:

```
for(int i=0;i<(members*2);i++){

// members = 3;

 for(int i=0;i<(3*2);i++){

//Por lo que te queda:

 for(int i=0;i<(6);i++){
```

Entonces tenemos que la variable i va desde 0 hasta 6 por lo que son siete iteraciones en total.

Como bien dice el compañero Luis simplemente restando una iteracion se quedaria el resultado del algoritmo como deseas:

```
//Menor o igual

 for(int i=0;i<=(members*2);i++){
```

En este caso si que serian 6 iteraciones puesto que la variable controladora del bucle FOR si que va, en este ultimo caso, desde 0 hasta 5 con lo que tendrias tu algoritmo correcto.

Comment: 7 iteraciones??? te equivocas. En un bucle `for` el orden de ejecución es: 1. Inicialización (`i=0`) 2. Se verifica la condición `i<=members*2` 3. Se ejecuta el contenido del bucle 4. El incremento `i++` 5. Vuelta al punto 2. Así pues es facil verificar que el contenido del bucle se ejecutará **exactamente** `member*2` veces. El recorrido de la séptima iteración que comentas ocupará únicamente el incremento y la validación de la condición ... al no cumplirla el bucle se abandonará y no habrá 7ª ejecución